# How to check if browser supports HTML5 postMessage? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Long story short, I'm using youtube iframe api and it requires browser to support HTML5 postMessage.

What i want to do is to check if is supported by user's browser

```
if (postMsgSupported) {
```

You get the idea, how could i do this?

Comment: `if (window.postMessage)` maybe?

Comment: `typeof window.postMessage === 'function'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

```js
if (window.postMessage) {
  console.log("support postMessage");
} else{
  console.log("Does not support postMessage ");
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, can also 'document.activeElement' be used like this?

Comment: You can get details about `activeElement` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement